# What is the 64 bit version of GetTextExtent

Tags: windows, 64-bit

I'm porting our 32 bit windows app to 64 bit, and trying to clean up all the warnings.  I have found calls in our code to CDC::GetTextExtent which take an int as a parameter.

I notice that GetTextExtent simply calls GetTextExtentPoint32.  The 32 scares me, so i started looking for a 64 bit version of GetTextExtent but i can't find one.

Can anyone tell me is GetTextExtent totally safe in 64 bit?  Or is there some other way we're supposed to get that information?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation, GetTextExtentPoint32 was added in 32-bit operating systems in order to provider more accurate results (I guess GetTextExtentPoint had a few limitations).  All of the parameters are identical, so it doesn't have anything to do with 16-bit vs 32-bit vs 64-bit as far as I can tell.  It would have made more sense to call it GetTextExtentPointEx or something, but what's done is done.